# Transparent Gradient Toolbar

Tags: java, android, toolbar, gradient, transparent

I am trying to make toolbar gradient with transparent but nothing is working. Here is my code.

activity_main.xml **(Updated)**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.amrat.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**gradient.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#00ffffff"
        android:startColor="#ffffff"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Trying to do like this:

[image: Expected]

But got this:

[image: Reality]

Please help me if anyone knows how to do this.

**UPDATE**

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent.NoActionBar" />
```

style.xml

```
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/light_grey_1</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/orange_1</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/light_grey_2</item>
</style>
```

Comment: why are not setting transparent color directly into toolbar instead of creating gradient background

Comment: Its already transparent but you are missing some theme behaivors. Send your manifest and styles.xml

Comment: @Bhavnik because I don't want full transparent toolbar. See Expected image.

Comment: @EmreAktürk added in post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@android:color/transparent` directly. Follow this one - 
**toolbar layout -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/background_toolbar_transparent" />
```

**background_toolbar_transparent.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:startColor="@color/black_alpha"/>
</shape>
```

Add a `color` with `alpha`on colors.xml -

```
<color name="black_alpha">#66000000</color>
```

Comment: Dont you want any gradient background?  Just need transparency ?? So, just use `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` on `toolbar` layout instead of `android:background="@drawable/background_toolbar_transparent"` .

Comment: Bro your code was working, I just applied it wrongly. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `start` and `end` colors to transparent.

```
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Apply the background gradient to `AppBarLayout` only and leave toolbar background.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <!-- Your content comes here -->

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/layout_toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       android:elevation="6dp"
       tools:targetApi="lollipop"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

[Frame Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) basically works as stack and the last added item comes to top.

Good luck

Emre

Comment: You mean I should remove AppBarLayout ?

Comment: Yes replace whoel content with mines unless there is a reason to keep it